# Virtual Camera Modus in OBS turn video into green / pink glitch (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, loopback, obs-studio

I want to use my Sony Alpha 6100 as a virtualcam via OBS on Ubuntu 22.04. OBS also finds my camera as input via gphoto2 and v4l2loopback-dkms. The image appears in OBS and looks good.
As soon as I want to switch to Virtual Camera mode only green and pink pixels are displayed. Sometimes my camera image is visible for a millisecond.

Unfortunately, I had the same problem with Ubuntu 21.04 and 20.04 and haven't found a solution yet. Does anyone know if I can change something in the settings? I have already disabled security boot and installed OBS via snap.

Screenshot of Virtual Camera Modus:
[image]

Comment: Have you try to change the USB cable?

Comment: yes, nothing changes. I also have a dual boot and everything works on Windows